# Mutable and Immutable Data Access

Tags: rust

This question will likely be really basic, but I don't even know what to search for.
I didn't see anything that jumped out at me in The Book, and I'm a Rust beginner:

```
struct Node;
impl Node {
    fn children(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<Node> {
        // Pulls a field out of Node, to be mutated
    }
    fn next_node(&self) -> Node {
        // Produces a new value using values computed from self.
        // Doesn't hold a reference to self
    }
}
[...]
if self.children().len() > K {
    let mut next_node = self.next_node();
    let list = self.children();
    // something involving next_node and list
}
```

This is what I eventually got to convince Rust that what I was doing was ok.
What I found more straight-forward was:

```
let list = self.children();
if list.len() > K {
    let mut next_node = self.next_node();
    // Something involving next_node and list
}
```

But it complained because I couldn't get an immutable reference to `self` in `next_node` because there was already a mutable one held up in `self.children`, which is true.

In particular in this implementation I only do `.children()` once, which in this case isn't a very complicated method, but could be.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't compute `children` more than once, and doesn't construct `next_node` when it's not required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: **no**.

---

Rust can reason about disjoint fields when borrowing, so you can mutably borrow a field and then borrow *another* field and it'll work, so long as both occur in the same context (function/method).

In this case what `next_node` does is opaque to the compiler, and it may actually be using the children for all we know.

Thus, it is required that when calling `next_node` no mutable borrow be outstanding.

---

> In particular in this implementation I only do `.children()` once, which in this case isn't a very complicated method, but could be.

True... but what's the responsibility of this method. Why would it perform *both* an extensive computation *and* a borrow?

The simpler organization of this code would be:

- do the expensive computation once (not borrowing)
- borrow for as a small a scope as possible

and it would work:

```
self.expensive_computation();

if self.children.len() > K {
    let mut next_node = self.next_node();
    let list = self.children;
    // Something involving next_node and list
}
```